# Write .odt file from Emacs text buffer

Tags: emacs

I've got a text buffer with some italics, indicated in each case by the italic text
property. All I want to do is somehow write a .odt file from Emacs, which appears
exactly same as the text buffer content. Do I have to wrestle with XML to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can write Markdown and then convert it to OpenDocument using [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/demos.html) as follows:

```
pandoc file.md -o file.odt
```